What Are the Alternatives to the Deprecated Instagram API and How to Transition to the New API?
I recently encountered a challenge while transitioning my application to the new Instagram API, as the previous API my app relied on has been deprecated. Since then, my app has stopped functioning, and I am unable to make successful requests using my developer account application.
Problem Details
I am attempting to use the new Instagram API but encounter the same error response for all requests I send. Below are the details of the requests I am making and the error received:
Requests Sent:

GET https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_type,media_url,caption,permalink&access_token={access_token}

GET https://graph.instagram.com/refresh_access_token?grant_type=ig_refresh_token&access_token={access_token}


Error Response for Both Requests
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'refresh_access_token' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "A8iDwownMK6B6Ch2Dyn6aMw"
  }
}

What I’ve Tried

I reviewed the Instagram Graph API documentation to ensure the endpoints I am using are correct.

Verified the access token format and expiration date.

Checked the permissions associated with my developer account and app.


What I Am Expecting
I would like assistance with the following:

How can I resolve the "Unsupported get request" error? Are there any specific permissions or configurations I need to update in my developer account?

What are the correct pathways to transition to the new Instagram API, and how can I authenticate and retrieve media data successfully?

Are there additional steps I need to take to refresh the access token and prevent such errors in the future?


Any insights, suggestions, or documentation references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!
